# dc.js: Change x-axis Increments

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I feel like this is a pretty simple problem, but I can't seem to find the right option to get this to work.

My chart currently looks like:

[image]

```
rowType
    .width(450).height(200)
    .dimension(countByType)
    .group(countByTypeGroup)
    .elasticX(true)
    .title(function(d) { return "$" + formatNumber(d.value) });
```

I just want to make it so that the x-axis increments by 50,000 instead of 20,000.

When I apply filters, those increments do change, but as the image shows, the current increments lead to the numbers bunching up.

I've tried using `rowType.xAxis().tickValues([0, 50000, 100000, 150000, 200000]);`
but if there are values that go beyond that range, the x axis does not show values that aren't in the array. Trying to use `.ticks(5)` did not seem to work well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rowType.xAxis().ticks(5) has worked for me in the past. Not for you? What version of dc.js?

Comment: Ah, I was just using the example number of ticks (5) in the question, but I actually only tried numbers 7-9. When using those numbers, it doesn't actually change the intervals. Using 5, however, did lower the intervals.

I also stumbled across the documentation here: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#linear_ticks
which does also reiterate the point that the count number won't be exactly followed.
Thanks for the response!